# Is there any option to find code smells in my program on the IDE itself?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

I want to find out the code smells while I am writing the code in the IDE instead of getting code smells after pushing my changes to Repository on the code analysis tolls like SonarQube tools etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an extension which you can integrate with your IDE which gives you realtime code smells and bugs. Please use this link

https://www.sonarlint.org/